# The view bonet.decorators.wrapper_func didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, decorator

[error at loading profile**Error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHzSj.png)

**Error**

**The view bonet.decorators.wrapper_func didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead**

Hii!! I'm new to stackoverflow and I'm getting this error and I'm not getting proper solution for this so plzz help me out to get out of this error

My view.py:

```py
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['customer'])
def profile(request):
    return render(request, 'bonet/profile.html')

@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['customer'])
def account_settings(request):
    customer = request.user.customer
    form = CustomerForm(instance=customer)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=customer)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()


    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'bonet/account_settings.html', context)
```